# Не могу подключить к серверу больше одного клиента

Tags: java, сервер, сокет, chat, client

```
package Server;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Server {

        public static ArrayList<Socket> clients = new ArrayList<Socket>();

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        ConnectWithServer.Connect();
    }
}

class ServerWork implements Runnable{

    Socket client;

    public ServerWork(Socket socket) {
        this.client = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try{


            Scanner input = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

            Server.clients.add(client);

            System.out.println("Server start");

            output.println("Enter your name: ");

            String name = input.nextLine();

            output.println("Hello, " + name);

            while(input.hasNextLine()) {
                String str = input.nextLine();
                if(str.equals("exit")) {

                    System.out.println(name + " exit");
                    Server.clients.remove(client);

                    break;

                }else {

                    System.out.println(name + " write: " + str);
                    for(Socket i : Server.clients) {
                        output.println(name + " write: " + str);
                    }

                }
            }

            System.out.println("Server stop");

        }catch(Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class ConnectWithServer{
    public static void Connect() throws Exception{

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(9090);
        Socket client = server.accept();
        new Thread(new ServerWork(client)).start();

    }
}
```

Comment: Вы один раз делаете `accept()` один клиент и подсоединяется...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно заменить

```
Socket client = server.accept();
new Thread(new ServerWork(client)).start();
```

на

```
while(true){
   Socket client = server.accept();
   new Thread(new ServerWork(client)).start();
}
```